# How to get rid of flickering form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am designing a Win Form in VB.NET and Using Table layout in it.
Problem i facing is , My WinForm is flickering every time it is load.

Kindly suggest me permanent solution in VB.NET.
Why this problem occurs? Is it because of Table Layout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting [`DoubleBuffered` form property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered) to "true".

Answer (score 5):

If you added any code to the Load event of the form that manipulates the UI use SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() to prevent flickering.

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with flickering after the form had loaded. Tried all advice without any real success. Stumbled on this piece of magic code somewhere while Googling the issue. Solved it 100% for me. Simply copy and paste it in form code. Well done to the author. When all else fails, try this.

```
Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or 33554432
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Indeed it works like a charm. Some explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455305/flickering-and-createparams

Answer (score -1):

I found a substantial improvement on one of my forms where double-buffering had done very little by adding

```
Me.Visible = False
```

early in the Form Load event.