# Form flickering after a minimize happened in mdi parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, doublebuffered

I used the code here

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718648/2006502

to prevent flickering of form(MDI form). And the code (to turning on WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag written in my MDI parent form) also affect all child form in which the above is MDI Parent. That is no flickering on any form load. The problem is when i minimize the MDI Form and then maximise, the all child forms started flickering on load. Can any one have an idea?

Comment: There is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455305/flickering-and-createparams) but this issue is down to overlapping controls trying to draw, its almost impossible to resolve (or at least the solution isn't shared much!)

Comment: @Sayse in that **Elektro Hacker** saying that it is slowing down the entire application, what u think?

Comment: Shaheed, I've still yet to find the solution to the problem, I and the users have just learned to live with it as it isn't a major part of the program